# Leetcode #2, getting detected a cycle error

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying to solve leetcode#2, You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.
https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/
I am getting Error: cycle detected only for additon of single digit numbers.
What am I doing wrong?

```
class Solution {
  public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode newpointer = null,
    mover = null;
    ListNode p = l1,
    q = l2;
    int carry = 0;
    while (p != null || q != null) {
      int x = (p == null) ? 0 : p.val;
      int y = (q == null) ? 0 : q.val;
      int sum = carry + x + y;
      carry = sum / 10;
      int digit = sum % 10;
      ListNode newnode = new ListNode();
      newnode.val = digit;
      newnode.next = null;
      if (newpointer == null) {
        newpointer = newnode;
        mover = newpointer;
      }
      mover.next = newnode;
      mover = mover.next;

      if (p != null) p = p.next;
      if (q != null) q = q.next;
    }
    if (carry > 0) {
      mover.next = new ListNode(carry);

    }

    return newpointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a link to the LC question.

Comment: I think the problem is `mover.next = newnode;` Does it show which line causes the error?

Comment: @EugeneMamaev thanks :) , why didn't I think of this!

Comment: @limido No, it doesnt say the line.
Input:
[0]
[0]
Output:
Error - Found cycle in the ListNode
Expected:
[0]

Comment: What happens if the two lists are different lengths?

Comment: Works fine @NomadMaker unless one number is single digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code snippet there are lines:

```
ListNode newnode = new ListNode();
...
if (newpointer == null) {
    newpointer = newnode;
    mover = newpointer;
}
mover.next = newnode;
```

It makes the LC cycle detection algorithm complain.

If you consider the first run of the `while` loop, you can find that `mover` points to the same object to which `newnode` does.

In other words, object `ListNode newnode = new ListNode();` ends up with a cyclic edge to itself after `mover.next = newnode;`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some redundant pointers and checks. Because they are in reversed order it is the natural order of summation. I think my code explains itself but if you have questions let me know.

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode head = null;
    ListNode prev = null;
    int carry = 0;
    while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        final int sum = l1.val + l2.val + carry;
        ListNode cur = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
        if (head == null) {
            head = cur;
        } else {
            prev.next = cur;
        }
        l1 = l1.next;
        l2 = l2.next;
        prev = cur;
    }
    ListNode remaining = l1 == null ? l2 : l1;
    while (remaining != null) {
        int sum = remaining.val + carry;
        ListNode cur = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
        prev.next = cur;
        remaining = remaining.next;
        prev = cur;
    }
    if (carry > 0) {
        prev.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: thankyou. I will go through your optimised code and let you know

Answer (score 0):

The bug you were getting seems to be already found in the accepted answer, yet we can just a bit simplify our statements for solving this problem to be more readable and easier to understand, if you will:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final ListNode addTwoNumbers(
        ListNode l1,
        ListNode l2
    ) {
        int carry = 0;
        final ListNode sentinel = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode tail = sentinel;

        while (!(l1 == null && l2 == null && carry == 0)) {
            final int add1 = l1 != null ? l1.val : 0;
            final int add2 = l2 != null ? l2.val : 0;
            final int sum = add1 + add2 + carry;
            carry = sum / 10;
            final ListNode tempNode = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            tail.next = tempNode;
            tail = tempNode;

            if (l1 != null) {
                l1 = l1.next;
            }

            if (l2 != null) {
                l2 = l2.next;
            }

        }

        return sentinel.next;
    }
}
```

We are using a [Sentinel Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) here.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.